# Ошибка инициализации в конструкторе C26495

Tags: c++, конструктор, инициализация

```
Mat::Mat() {
int a1[3][3] = {
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 }
};
int a2[3][3] = {
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 }
};
int a3[3][3] = {
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 },
    { 0,0,0 }
};

int aa[18] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };

int n = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int temp = 0;
int r = 0;}
```

Пишет 
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::temp' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).    Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::a1' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::a2' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::a3' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::aa' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).  Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::i' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::j' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::n' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7
Предупреждение  C26495  Variable 'Mat::r' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6).   Lab 1. n 4  c:\users\antgo\source\repos\lab 1. n 4\matr.cpp 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо ваш класс `Mat` содержит массивы и обьекты с такими именами, и вы пытаетесь инициализировать в конструкторе эти члены, но неудачно, так как вы определяете новые обьекты и массивы, придворяя их иммена именем типа. Таким образом оставляете члены неинициализированными. Просто **уберите** имя типа `int` и получите присвоение этих обьектов.

```
a1[3][3] = ...
a2[3][3] = ..
//...    
n = 0;
i = 0;
//...
```

P.S. Чтобы инициализировать все элементы массива нулем(значением по умолчанию), достаточно инициализировать только первый:

```
aa[18] = { 0 };
```